# Combination of operators in operator overloading

Tags: c++

I Need To Do Combination of Operator Overloading in my code.

For example :

When I write x[i] it returns a value, this much I know. What I need to know, is how to make the operator function so that if it's alone, it returns the value inside, and if it's followed by equal (x[i] = val) it sets the value of x[i].

Comment: Ever heard of punctuation?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking, but [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)?

Comment: You'll need to return either an lvalue reference or a proxy class.  Which depends on how the type of `x` is set up and what those expressions need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding what happens in the statement `x[i] =  val`. Assume your operator overload looks like this:

```
item_type & operator[](int index);
```

Then the `[]` operator is returning a reference to some object of type `item_type`. So we can replace `x[i]` with:

```
(item_type &) = val
```

The `=` operator is thus applied to the value of `item_type &`, not the original `x` type. If `item_type` supplies an assignment operator, then this works. If it doesn't, then it doesn't.

Comment: U Mean That when I use x[i] = val , it'll understand that the target is x[i] not x ??

Comment: Yes, because ``x[i]`` will be evaluated before ``=`` is.

Comment: but what if the implementation of the overloaded operator as this; in which the existence of the operator after the object will lead to returning a value 

example : http://codepad.org/fFYysePI

Comment: When i try to assign a value to it , the IDE tells me that the x[i] not required to be left operand , but it must be in the R.H.S.

Comment: In your example the return needs to be ``T &`` if you want it to mutate the value stored in ``x``. Otherwise you're just mutating a copy that's created as the return for the operator. Also having a default return of 0 for a templated return type of ``T`` is invalid if ``T`` is not castable to ``int``. It needs to either throw an exception or have undefined behavior (such as returning ``T()``, which could do anything including be a compile-time failure).

Comment: [This is a handy-dandy reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading#Subscript_operator) for operator overloading in general in C++ (jumped to the subscript operator)